# Dependency analysis in a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, software-verification

I was reading [[1]](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Ealessio/papers/20/aaai20-BKKLM.pdf) about verifying neural networks. $n_{i,r}$ refers to the rth neuron in layer i and all neurons have the ReLU activation function. A neuron $n_{i,r}$ is said to be strictly active if its pre-activation output is always greater than or equal to zero. Similarly, $n_{i,r}$ is said to be strictly inactive if its pre-activation output is always negative. $n_{i,r}$ is stable if it is strictly active OR strictly inactive. otherwise it is unstable.

2 unstable neurons $n_{i,r}$ and $n_{j,k}$ are said to have a dependency relation if $n_{i,r}$ being stable implies $n_{j,k}$ is stable.

My question is about the dependency between 2 neurons in the same layer. $x_{i,q,r=0}$ refers to the pre-activation output of $n_{i,q}$ given that the pre-activation of $n_{i,r}$ is 0. $u_{i,q,r=0}$ is the upper bound of $x_{i,q,r=0}$ while $l_{i,q,r=0}$ is its lower bound.

Lemma 1 on page 4 of [[1]](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Ealessio/papers/20/aaai20-BKKLM.pdf) states that

$$ (n_{i,q} = active => n_{i,r} = inactive) <=> (u_{i,q,r=0} \lt 0 and u_{i,r,q=0} < 0) $$

I understand the => direction. The pre-activation of $n_{i,q} \ge 0$ INCLUDES the case where the pre-activation of $n_{i,q} = 0$. this means

$n_{i,q} \ge 0 => n_{i,r} < 0$ automatically implies $u_{i,r,q=0} < 0 $. Similarly, the contrapositive of the LHS automatically implies $u_{i,q,r=0} \lt 0$.

I don't understand the <= direction. In the proof for =>, it seems like the RHS was just stating a subset of what the LHS is saying. I tried writing a few statements and taking contrapositives but I am not able to prove RHS => LHS, I just keep going in circles and proving the same thing. Can anyone help with a formal proof OR an intuition about why this is true?

References:

1. [Efficient Verification of ReLU-based Neural Networks via Dependency Analysis](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Ealessio/papers/20/aaai20-BKKLM.pdf)

Comment: Wont all ReLu neurons be strictly active? (Since the output of the ReLu is always non-negative)

Comment: I've edited it now, but stability is determined by pre-activation output. sorry and thanks for pointing it out